# FSharp type inference, not able to set properties on dotnet objects

Tags: f#, type-inference

I wonder if this approach (setting properties) is supposed to work. I am getting FS0001 (This expression was expected to have type ''a-> 'b' but here has type 'SqlConnection') on the line 17 (cmd.Connection <| conn) and the same for string for the line 18 (cmd.CommandText <| "select getdate() as d"). Code snippet:

```html
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient

[<Literal>]
let ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    let cmd = new SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection <| conn
    cmd.CommandText <| "select getdate() as d"
    let da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    let ds = new DataSet()
    da.Fill ds |> ignore
    printfn "result is"
    0
```

I was able to get data from database using other libraries. What I would like to achieve in addition is to be able to translate C# code used in many places to F# without having to add specific dependencies (to just overcome the type inference issues).

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: Property mutation syntax is `<-`, not `<|`

Comment: `<-`, not `<|`.

Comment: Protect your resources by using `use` instead of `let`. Otherwise you'll risk runtime errors appearing randomly at runtime.

Comment: Use the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of the old System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Suggestions well noted!

Answer (score 1):

as Fyodor Soiking and Travis (comments) have pointed out a simple syntax issue was actually the problem.

Correct approach to assign a property is to use "<-" instead of "<|".

Thanks a lot!
Alex